# Ссылка на массив в объекте

Tags: javascript

Cвойство  **place** в объекте **meetup** это циклическая ссылка?

Если нет, то каким правильным термином это называть?

```js
let massive = [1];

let meetup = {
  title: "Conference",
  participants: [{name: "John"}, {name: "Alice"}],
  place: massive // Вот это циклическая ссылка?
}

alert(Object.values(meetup.place));
```

Comment: когда вы сам объект meetup добавите в массив massive, тогда можно будет говорить как-то о цикличности. Пока что это обычное поле с массивом.

Comment: @teran, а как добавить meetup в массив, чтобы посмотреть на циклическую ссылку. Покажите пожалуйста)

Comment: `let meetup = {
  title: "Conference",
}; meetup.cycleMeetup = meetup;` Вот в поле `cycleMeetup` содержится ссылка на `meetup`, которое содержит поле `cycleMeetup`, в котором содержится ссылка на `meetup`...